# Why React doesn't upload image to server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, multer

I have an app using react and express on the backend and multer to manage the upload. The server side is running properly when I make tests using postman, but if trait to send an image from react the result is unexpected. In that case the file doesn't appear in the uploads folder, however with postman is immediatly.

*UploadPage,jsx*

```
 const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

 const onSubmit = async (data)  => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('petimage', data.petimage);
        try {
            const res = await axios.post('/api/petregister', formData);
            console.log(res)
        } catch (error) {
            setError(error.response.data.error);
            setTimeout(() => {
                setError("");
            }, 5000);
        } 
    }
    
    return (
        <Container className="mt-5">
                    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                        <Form.Group controlId="formFile" className="mb-3">
                            <Form.Label>Imagen de tu Mascota</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="file" 
                                label="Select image"
                                name="petimage"
                                 {...register("petimage")}
                            />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                    </Form>
       </Container>
```

**Google Response**

[image]

The fields with name **petimage** are the same that I expecified in the backend and used these in the postman tests.

**Edit**

```
const store = require('../middlewares/multer');

route.post('/petregister', store.array('petimage', 12), petregister);
```

The last section of code is the route that is linked with the multer midleware asigned to ssave the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was trait the image as an object. The code is the next:

```
Object.values(data.petimage).forEach(pet => formData.append('petimage', pet))
```

Then it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you are making a API call to the backend, it will upload the image to the specific folder that you are defining in the backend like :

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: 'folder path' });
```

I think you are getting results unexpected because the name for the image you are giving in formData `formData.append('petimage', data.petimage);` i.e petimage, it should be the same in the multer fileupload method. You haven't shared the backend code. So, I'm hoping that it may be like this:

`var fileUpload = upload.single('petimage');` when the name is the same it will work fine.

If the image is of big size, you can compress it. Please visit this link, it will help you for sure.
https://dev.to/franciscomendes10866/image-compression-with-node-js-4d7h

Comment: effectively the name that is provided in the back side is the same I'm using in the react field, and the application of this is close of your suggestion. In a couple minutes I'll edit my question with parts of the back code. Thanks for your helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

Remove

```
formData.append('petimage', data.petimage);
```

and use instead

```
data.petimage.forEach(pet => formData.append("petimage", pet))
```

Comment: I'm getting "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): data.petimage.forEach is not a function". What could be the mistake?

Comment: ForEach method is valid in that file format?? I understand your logic and think that is correct, only have doubts about forEach in an image. Maybe need to convert in an object before run the bucle.